# keras activation function layer: model.add Activation('relu') gives invalid syntax

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

```
    model = sequential ()
    model.add(convolutional2D(32,3,3 , input_shape = (img_width, 
    img_height,3))
    model.add(Maxpooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(convolutional2D(32,3,3))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxpoolingD2(pooling_size=(2,2)))

    model.add(convolutional2D(32,3,3,))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Maxpooling2D(pooling_size=(2,2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(dense(64))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(dropout(0.5))
    model.add(dense(1))
    model.add(activation(sigmoid))
```

please someone should help out. I use jupyter notebook in python 2.7 environment and the above code returns:

```
 File "<ipython-input-11-fab080993955>", line 4
model.add(Activation('relu'))
    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a parenthesis at the end in this line:

`model.add(convolutional2D(32,3,3 , input_shape = (img_width, img_height,3))`

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-1b21d60feafc> in <module>()
      1 #step 2 _ build model
----> 2 model = sequential ()
      3 model.add(convolutional2D(32,3,3 , input_shape = (img_width, img_height,3)))
      4 model.add(Activation('relu'))
      5 model.add(Maxpooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

NameError: name 'sequential' is not defined

Comment: I had this after fixing the parenthesis

Comment: its Sequential, not sequential.